# CSS backgrounds lines appearing on iOS

Tags: css, ios, background

I have 3 divs with backgrounds. IOS seams to add a white line between them on all formats from iPhone to iPAD. Originally I thought this was a problem with tables but it applies to divs too.

```
#cbtop {
    height:10px;
    background:url(http://www.golfbrowser.com/images/structure/cbmain.png) center top repeat-y;
}
#cbbottom {
    height:10px;
    background:url(http://www.golfbrowser.com/images/structure/cbmain.png) center bottom repeat-y;
}
#content {
    min-height:10px;
    background:url(http://www.golfbrowser.com/images/structure/cbmains.png) center top repeat-y;
}
```

seen here on iOS only - http://www.golfbrowser.com/courses/wentworth-east/

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Comment: What should it look like? It does look strange on Mac OSX Safari too, it's "ok" on firefox though, I am not sure what the result should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That white line is actually the two divs overlapping. This is a precision problem on iOS's safari, and is pretty much unavoidable (imho). The problem is most prominent when zooming in, as this is when the lack of precision occurs.

You *MAY* be able to "trick" the browser into working correctly by using a half-pixel top-margin on the bottom div... I have no way of testing this, however.

In this instance, I would use css border radius to accomplish the same effect... although it will not display properly in *all* browsers, you may still find it an acceptable solution

```
#cb
{
    background: rgb(255,255,255); // fallback for browsers without alpha support
    background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.5);

    border-radius: 30px;
}
```

There are also webkit and mozilla versions of the border radius property... this will help with cross-platform compatability.

See more on background alpha transparency here: http://robertnyman.com/2010/01/11/css-background-transparency-without-affecting-child-elements-through-rgba-and-filters/

See JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xixionia/4SYP4/